# Is the following valid XHTML 1.0 Transitional?

Tags: javascript, ampersand, xhtml-transitional

The w3c validator service complains that the following html is invalid. It does not like the ampersand(&) in my javascript. But ampersands are allowed in javascript strings, aren't they?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Page Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">


           function search(query) {
             redir = "http://search.mysite.com/search?s=FIN&ref=&q=" + query;
             window.location.href = redir
             return false;
            }
        </script>

        <span>This is all valid HTML</span>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: They are allowed in JavaScript string. But your JavaScript string is in HTML. And there it is not allowed.

Comment: http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is indeed not valid. If you want to use in-line JavaScript in an XHTML file, you'll need to wrap the JavaScript in [CDATA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA). If you don't want to do that, then you're stuck with encoding &, < and >, which in JavaScript can be quite a pain.

Answer (score 3):

All browsers will take this, but to make it valid X(HT)ML you need to put the Javascript code in a CDATA block.

Answer (score 2):

Even in javascript w3c validator don't like ampersands. Try to comment your javascript from validator

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Page Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[//><!--
           function search(query) {
             redir = "http://search.mysite.com/search?s=FIN&ref=&q=" + query;
             window.location.href = redir
             return false;
            }
        //--><!]]>
        </script>

        <span>This is all valid HTML</span>

    </body>
</html>
```